# How can I secure several azure web apps with one SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain, azure-webapps

I would like to know if it is possible to secure several azure web apps with one SSL Certificate.

Example:

webapp1.azurewebsite.net => app.com

webapp2.azurewebsite.net => app2.com

webapp3.azurewebsite.net => app3.com

3 different domains 1 one SSL Certificate

Comment: Yes, it's possible to secure multiple domains using a single SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wildcard cert, *.foo.com. They are usually more $$ than a non-wildcard cert, however.

Your scenario, won't support wildcards, however because your you are using top-level domains (a.com, b.com etc), if they were a.foo.com and b.foo.com that would work.

Another option, and I don't know which CAs support this, is to use Subject Alternate Names https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name